# Encoding AWS Affiliate API String with PS gives wrong hash

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, hash, affiliate

From the following guide in AWS I need to generate an HMAC SHA256 Signature:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html

My code is as follows:

```
$message = 'GET
webservices.amazon.com
/onca/xml
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&AssociateTag=mytag-20&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2013-08-01'

$secret = '1234567890'

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

echo $signature

# Do we get the expected signature?
echo ($signature -eq 'j7bZM0LXZ9eXeZruTqWm2DIvDYVUU3wxPPpp+iXxzQc=')
```

Unfortunately I do not get the same hash as AWS does in it's example. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I got it eventually.
It had something to do with the line breaks:

```
$message = "GET`nwebservices.amazon.com`n/onca/xml`nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&AssociateTag=mytag-20&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2013-08-01"
```